# App Store Connect Operation Error when Validating App with Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

The server returned an invalid response. This may indicate that a network is interfering with comminication, or that Apple servers are haveing issues. Please try your request again later
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGJWo.png)
I am using Xcode 12.5 to validate my flutter app after running
flutter build ipa
[my network proxy setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOZYT.png)

I have double confirmed that no proxy is in my networking setting

Comment: was this error solved?